# Returning Multiple Query Results To Various View Sections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I have two divs a "Most Popular" and an "Ending Soon".

I want to display the most popular items in my database and those items who's auction date is "ending soon".

Using the commented out code, in the `Index()` controller, in the code below, I am successfully able to query the database for the "Most Popluar" items, and return those results to the page. But I am trying to return both sets of data to the page --most popular and items ending soon, for the partial view **_AuctionTile** to use?

I have the query for the items ending soon.

The solution below, represents a solution path I have set out upon to achieve being able to return both sets of data --most popular and items ending soon to the view. I guess I have two questions:

1) Why can't I do something like this:

```
var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
var mostPopular = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount).ToArray();
var endingSoon = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.EndTime).ToArray();
return View(mostPopular, endingSoon);
```

2) Considering the solution path that is what I have posted below, and going with creating two lists structures in a view model,  why is the property `mostPopularItems` not being detected up by Intellisense as existing as shown in the screenshot?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.mostPopularItems)
```

The View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyAuctionApp.Models.Auction>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">

    <div id="popular" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Most Popular Items</h2>

        @foreach (var item in Model.mostPopularItems)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)

        }
</div>

<div id="ending" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h2>Auctions Ending Soon</h2>
       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           @Html.Partial("_AuctionTile", item)
        }
 </div>
```

The ViewModel

```
using MyAuctionApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyAuctionApp.ViewModels
{

public class AuctionViewModel
    {
    public static List<Auction> mostPopularItems;
    public static List<Auction> endingSoon;

        public AuctionViewModel(AuctionsDataContext db)
        {
        mostPopularItems = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > 
DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount).ToList();
        endingSoon = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > 
DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.EndTime).ToList();
        }
   }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
using MyAuctionApp.Models;
using MyAuctionApp.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyAuctionApp.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class HomeController : Controller

      {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
       var dataModuleObject = new AuctionViewModel(db);
       return View(dataModuleObject);

      //var auctions = db.Auctions.ToArray();
     //var auctions = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > 
     //DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount);
     //return View(auctions);
         }
     }
```

As you can see from the attached screenshot however, the `mostPopularItems` 
property that was initialized in the `AuctionViewModel`, is not being picked 
up by Intellisense as existing, in the line

```
@foreach (var item in Model.mostPopularItems)
```

[image]

Your solutions are welcome.  But please, I am new to this process.  So assume I need you to spell everything out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the properties `mostPopularItems` and `endingSoon` because in your view model you define them as `static`. And in you view you're using this line:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.mostPopularItems)
```

That will not work because Model contains an instance of AuctionViewModel and static can only access through the class itself not from an instance.

You need to refactor your code. The view model must look like this:

```
public class AuctionViewModel
{
    public List<Auction> mostPopularItems {get; set; }
    public List<Auction> endingSoon {get; set; }

        public AuctionViewModel(AuctionsDataContext db)
        {
            mostPopularItems = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount).ToList();
            endingSoon = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.EndTime).ToList();
        }
   }
}
```

Change your wiew model type by doing this:

```
@model MyAuctionApp.ViewModels.AuctionViewModel
```

So after that refactoring, your foreach code will work correctly.

Comment: Thank you.  I now understand the difference between an instance variable and a static variable, as it relates to accessing their properties, now, more than ever.  Amazing stuff.

Comment: A db context should not be in your view model - its the responsibility of the controller to populate the data (and this would never work if you were editing data)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Indeed. But here he is just displaying the data.  
For the architecture issue I saw that. But because the questionner seems to be a novice (he just learn what is static and instance members) I think it will  fix the current problem. As long as he continues to code he will see the problem or learn somewhere that he is not following a good practice. We all learn by doing mistakes :-)